# Split a text using comma but ignore any character inside string

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a weird situation, I need to split a text like below using delimeter`(,)` but have to ignore comma inside string. I have acheived it using regex pattern `,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`

Now problem is my text contains strings but also contain a lone double quote`(")`. I cant change the text as this data is being generated by some data engine.

Here is my text which needs to be splitted-

> 355,170102,204500,204509,10,"SOME TEXT 10"","COM","COM","Not Split"

Please note there is an extra double quote in`"SOME TEXT 10""` which is not in pair. Because of this Split is not working for this type of text.

I am expecting result as below-

```
355
170102
204500
204509
10
"SOME TEXT 10"
"COM"
"COM"
"Not Split"
```

but getting result as-

```
355,170102,204500,204509,10,"SOME TEXT 10""
"COM"
"COM"
"Not Split"
```

How to acheive this? Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to define the rules in detail. If this is common CSV input, there should be an escape character defined and a common example looks like so  `123,"Text""with quotest"` - reason: If this extra quote has no escape charater and is allowed to be everywhere in your text and texts are allowed to contain commas, then it's impossible to split it. Example: `"This "funny","short" example"` - does it mean `This "funny`, `short" example` or `This "funny","shrt" example`?

Comment: Btw.: If this is CSV input, I'd consider to use a lib instead because CSV has edge cases. See e.g. CSVHelper.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Can CSVHelper deal with "wild", unescaped quotation marks in the field contents? Like here, with `"SOME TEXT 10""`?

Comment: CSVHelper can't help with non-standard CSV files (which this appears to be).  I'd be tempted to go back to wherever you got this file from and ask why there is an unescaped double quote.

Comment: Is this example column correct `"SOME TEXT 10""` or is should it be `""SOME TEXT 10""?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the question. Can you not simply match on `[^,"]+`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iUEks/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to change your regex to:

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*""?)*[^"]*$)
```

which adds and additional, optional `"` after the closing double-quote of the string, then you would end up with the following splits:

```
355
170102
204500
204509
10
"SOME TEXT 10""
"COM"
"COM"
"Not Split"
```

The problem is the `"SOME TEXT 10""` string, which you might be able to live with. However, if you further modify the regex to:

```
(?<=^[^"]*"[^"]*")",|,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*""?)*[^"]*$)
```

which will also split on `",` when it is preceded by the first quoted string of the input and yield:

```
355
170102
204500
204509
10
"SOME TEXT 10"
"COM"
"COM"
"Not Split"
```

[See C# Demo](https://ideone.com/CUSnMc)